# Redirect URI mismatch, why?

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, youtube, http-status-code-400, youtube-analytics-api

Following the directions here using latest/last python 2.7:

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python

For the https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/retrieve_reports.py script

Google oAuth explorer tests seem to work fine. URI authorized redirects are set in GCP to the following:

http://localhost/8080
http://localhost/

Running python retrieve_reports.py on my console with no changes to the above reporting script (other than inserting my credentials.json file)

I get the following on the Google oAuth page:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request,
> urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native
> application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create
> a Client ID for native application at
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

I've seen online I may need to use a public URI, but I'm not sure what that would be in my case...

Edit: I started using httP://127.0.0.1 as my redirect URI because of others saying online port numbers mess it up as well as URI that are not actual IP addresses.

Also, when I set up my credentials for a desktop app (not what Google's github documentation says, which recommends a webapp), I get a different error 400:

Error 400: invalid_request

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

> You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with
> one or more Google validation rules. The content in this section has
> been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed
> or verified by Google. If you’re the app developer, make sure that
> these request details comply with Google policies.
>
> ```
> redirect_uri: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
> ```